# Find derivative of [(4-pi)/(4pi) x^2 - 10x + 100]?

Tags: calculus

How do I find derivative of this equation?

my attempt:

A(x) = $$\frac{4x^2+\pi x^2}{4\pi}-10x+100.$$

so how do I find the derivative of the first part? Like do I use quotient rule for the beginning of the equation??

please show full solutions :)

thanks

Sincerely,

Math should solve itself, I have my own problems!!

Comment: In case you are going to get the derivative of the term in the third line of your posting we have to know if you want to know the derivative in respect to $x$ or $\pi$.  Please show full attempts.  And I doubt that your proposition: “Math should solve itself.” can be derived under your assumption: “I have my own problems.”  Please show full attempts on your work on this as well, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{4x^2+\pi x^2}{4\pi}-10x+100\right)'=\left(\frac{4+\pi}{4\pi}x^2-10x+100\right)'=\left(\frac{4+\pi}{4\pi}(x^2)'-10x'+100'\right)$$
$$=\frac{4+\pi}{4\pi}2x-10=\frac{4+\pi}{2\pi}x-10$$

Comment: would second derivative be 4+pi/2pi ?

Comment: That is correct, Jesse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Factor out the $x^2$. You'll simply be left with a quadratic polynomial. No need for quotient rule (though you can of course use it).

Comment: thanks but how do I find the derivative of (4-pi)/(4pi) when I factor the x^2 out? I know how to find the derivative of the quadratic but what about the (4-pi)/(4pi) at the front?

Comment: Well, how do you find the derivative of a constant?

Comment: wait how is it a constant? so it's just zero?

Comment: @CameronBuie It seems that your hint wasn't useful to Jesse at all.  (Despite he factored out wrong.)

Comment: since there's no x? wow I'm such a genius :( thank you!

Comment: Michael makes a good point, @Jesse. You should have $$A(x)=\frac{4+\pi}{4\pi}x^2-10x+100$$ once you've factored.

Comment: oops *SHE factored out wrong (4+pi)/(4pi) oh god so this is a constant?

Comment: @Jesse: Yes, you've just got a formula of the form $$ax^2+bx+c,$$ where $a=\frac{4+\pi}{4\pi},$ $b=-10,$ and $c=100$. What is the derivative of such a general formula when $a,b,c$ are constants?

Comment: @CameronBuie zero?

Comment: @Jesse: I'm afraid not. What method are you using to calculate the derivative?

Comment: @CameronBuie im not sure what you were asking but you said a, b and c, in your equation are constants and the derivative of a constant doesn't have a slope cuz its zero. But anyways I get it now (since the guy below answered it for me) but thank you so much for forcing me to "THINK" except im not the brightest of the bunch so that would've never happened!! Thanks again!! :D

Comment: @Jesse: Ah! I see where your confusion was coming from. Yes, the derivatives of those *constants* would be zero. I was asking what the derivative of $ax^2+bx+c$ would be. Once you've found that, just plug in our specific values for $a,b,c$ as needed, and you'll get exactly the same answer that Madrit handed you. Don't sell yourself short. Your comment on Madrit's answer suggests to me that you understand this better than you think you do. If you tell yourself that you're not bright enough to think as an excuse to avoid it, then you're right...so *don't tell yourself that*.

Comment: @CameronBuie omg thank you so much!! Ever considered a profession in motivational speaking? I know the basics but when I saw the fraction with pi in the equation I just overanazlysed it assuming we would need to do quotient rule for (4-pi)/(4pi) and then the derivative of the x^2 -10x + 100 so I was like hahaha no thanks, but it's all good now :) Have a great day!!!

Comment: @CameronBuie and getting spoonfed is just sooo much better than actually thinking for yourself! Technology encourages it, so i might as well take advantage of it!!

Comment: @Jesse: I'm a math professor. Motivational speaking is a rather large part of my job, since many of my students are convinced that they aren't going to get what I'm talking about. ;-) I have to strenuously disagree with your evaluation of being spoonfed versus thinking for yourself. If you can do it yourself, then you never need to rely on the uncertainty of waiting for charity of others. True, technology makes it simpler, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.